# Bootstrap- background image with content overlay

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a background image, and have all of the content of my page on a white background on top of the image.

I've tried

```
.body {
  background: url('background.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and

```
html{
    /* This image will be displayed fullscreen */
    background:url('background.jpg') no-repeat center center;

    min-height:100%;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

but neither of them works. The first one changes nothing, and with the second I can see a small strip of my image at the bottom of my screen.

Here is my trimmed down code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="pics/icon.ico">

    <title>News</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body id="news">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <!---navbar content-->
        </nav>


    <div class="container" style="background:white;">

      <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
          <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
          </p>
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>headline</h1>
            <p>subheadline</p>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <!--content snipped-->
          </div><!--/row-->
        </div><!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->
      </div><!--/row-->

      <hr>

    <footer>
      <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
      <p>&copy; 2015 </p>
    </footer>

    </div><!--/.container-->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script src="offcanvas.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your style changes

```
body {
  background: url('background.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and html

```
 <div class="container" style="background:transparent;">
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work.Try this

```
    html{
      background-image: url('background.jpg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

and give background-color:white to the div or para wherever you want white background.

Answer (score 1):

First one, there is no "body" class,

```
.body { // if you want to choose body object, you have to remove dot
 background: url('background.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Second one, your container div has a background css

```
<div class="container" style="background:white;">
```